# Document still visible in My Drive after changing owner and removing all permissions

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the Google Drive API in C# to Copy, change owner and remove all permissions of a document, here is how I do it:

```
File file = User1DriveService.Files.Copy(fileWithTitleChanged, OriginalFile.Id).Fetch()

//new owner permission
Permission newOwnerPermission = new Permission();
newOwnerPermission.Value = User2Email;
newOwnerPermission.Type = "user";
newOwnerPermission.Role = "owner";
newOwnerPermission.WithLink = false;
User1DriveService.Permissions.Insert(newOwnerPermission, file.Id).Fetch();

//remove all permissions, using User2 DriveService
permissionList = User2DriveService.Permissions.List(file.Id).Fetch();

foreach (Permission CurrentPermission in permissionList.Items)
{
    User2DriveService.Permissions.Delete(file.Id, CurrentPermission.Id).Fetch();
}

//update name and folder for User2
File FileCopyProperties = new File();
FileCopyProperties.Parents = newParentReferenceList; //folder in User2 drive
FileCopyProperties.Title = NewFileTitle;
User2DriveService.Files.Update(FileCopyProperties, file.Id).Fetch();
```

Everything works fine, except that **User1** still see the document in his Drive. Not right away all the time but it always ends up showing, sometimes a few hours after the process. Also, I've ran a fake user permission insert/delete on those copied documents using the API, the documents disappear from User1 Drive but reappear again a few hours later. I can't even reach those documents using the API from User1. When I click on those documents from User1 it says I do not have access and need to request it.

Everything is fine on the User2 side.

This is not a browser cache problem as I've clear everything and changed browser, even computer many times.

Comment: Any one from Google can tell me if this is the correct method to change the document's owner?

Comment: UPDATE: I spoke with someone at Google a couple of weeks ago and everything is fine in my code, the problem is in the Drive frontend which might take a little while to fix based on what he said.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a consistency problem. You probably expect strong consistency, but notice eventual consistency.

As described on https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide#consistency the list operations are eventual consistent, while ACL is strong consistent. In other words: permissions work fine, while the list is updated at a later moment.

Comment: I've waited many days in some cases in order to make sure that this was not just a consistency issue, nothing changed, no matter how long I've waited...